# Use Circle of Output Negation for Input Negation with circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz, logic

I want to use the compact illustration for a not gate with another logic gate at the **input** of the logic gate. So far, the documentation shows me how to do this with the `ocirc`. But this looks different from the circle at the output. How can I get the same circle at the input?

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[european]{circuitikz}
\ctikzset{tripoles/european not symbol=ieee circle}
\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0) node[and port] (AND1) {}
(AND1.in 1) node[anchor=east] {$E_0$} 
(AND1.in 2) node[anchor=east] {$E_1$}
(AND1.out) node[anchor=west] {$A_0$};
\node at (AND1.bin 1) [ocirc, left]{};
\end{circuitikz}

\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0) node[nand port] (AND1) {}
(AND1.in 1) node[anchor=east] {$E_0$} 
(AND1.in 2) node[anchor=east] {$E_1$}
(AND1.out) node[anchor=west] {$A_0$};
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE Rendering]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from changing the output circle as in [Zarko's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/684913/38080), you can also use the shape `notcirc` (page 155 of the current manual):

```latex
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[european]{circuitikz}
\ctikzset{tripoles/european not symbol=ieee circle}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw   (0,0) node[nand port] (AND1) {}
        (AND1.in 1) node[anchor=east] {$E_0$}
        (AND1.in 2) node[anchor=east] {$E_1$}
        (AND1.out) node[anchor=west] {$A_0$};
\node at (AND1.bin 1) [ocirc, left]{};
\node at (AND1.bin 2) [notcirc, left]{};
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

So basically, it depends on what size you prefer...

Comment: Actually iz is first mentioned in section 4.22.2 IEEE logic gates, on page 153  (in frame before last)   :-). Thank you for info!

Comment: Thanks for the reference to the documentation. I have not seen the small part showing the `notcirc`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood you correctly. Like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[european]{circuitikz}
\ctikzset{tripoles/european not symbol=ieee circle}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw   (0,0) node[nand port] (AND1) {}
        (AND1.in 1) node[anchor=east] {$E_0$}
        (AND1.in 2) node[anchor=east] {$E_1$}
        (AND1.out) node[anchor=west] {$A_0$};
\node at (AND1.bin 1) [ocirc, left]{};
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

or with

```
\ctikzset{tripoles/european not symbol=circle}
```

you will get

[image]

**Note:**
Both are explained in the package documentation, section 4.22.7.1 European logic port customization, pp 163 and in 4.22.5.2 American logic port anchors, pp157.