# quantikz - drawing circuit with output in the middle

Tags: formatting, diagrams, circuitikz, circuits, quantikz

I'm currently trying to draw this circuit in the `quantikz` package:
[image: quantum circuit]

This is what I have so far (+ the output):

```
\begin{quantikz}
  \lstick{$\ket{x_1}$} & \gate{NOT} & \gate[2]{NAND} &            &                & \\
  \lstick{$\ket{x_2}$} & \gate{NOT} &                & \gate{NOT} & \gate[2]{NAND} & \qw \\
  \lstick{$\ket{x_3}$} & \gate{NOT} & \qw            & \qw        &                &
\end{quantikz}
```

[image: quantum circuit tikz output]

I feel like I'm pretty close here, but the main difference is that I'm not sure how to make the first NAND output be in the center of the gate -- it seems like it needs to stay with the ket{x_2} row. Is there any way to get the output to look similar to the drawn image, while using the `quantikz` package?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: It looks like you're trying to draw a wholly classical circuit for which [`circuitikz`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/circuitikz) would be much more appropriate. `quantikz` is explicitly for quantum circuits, in which the number of inputs and outputs of a quantum gate should always match.

Comment: Gotcha! I'll look into ``circuitikz`` in that case. Thank you!

Comment: With `circuitikz` you can do that using classic shapes for gates, either IEEE https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/684376/38080 or European https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/684906/use-circle-of-output-negation-for-input-negation-with-circuitikz